# error creating a checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["erp"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
string intero = "Select * from judete";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(intero, con);

SqlDataReader rdr;

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    CheckBoxList check = new CheckBoxList();
    check.Visible = true;

    check.Items.Add(new ListItem(rdr[1].ToString()));
    Panel1.Controls.Add(check);

    foreach (ListItem item in this.check)
    {

    }
```

I want to make a foreach in the checkboxlist but I get an error that I don't have a checkboxlist check despite that I'm creating it.Do you have any idea why my checkboxlist check isn't recognized? I'm using c# in an asp.net application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `this.` before `check` in the `foreach` loop and add `.Items` after it:

```
foreach (ListItem item in check.Items)
```

Reasons:

- `check` is a local variable and not a member variable.
- You want to enumerate the `Items` of the `CheckBoxList`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the CheckBoxList from code, you wont get the items from `this`. So use FindControl Method to get the Item. You should be giving an ID to your control when you create that

```
CheckBoxList check = new CheckBoxList();
check.ID="myCheck";
```

You can get the item like this

```
 CheckBoxList myCheck=(CheckBoxList) Panel1.FindControl("myCheck");
```

You can loop thru the Items collection of Checkbox list like this now

```
foreach (ListItem item in myCheck.Items)
{
     item.Text = rdr.GetString(2); //or whatever with GetOrdinal
}
```

Are you sure you want to create an instance of the Checkbox list inside the While loop or you just want to create only one instance of that (outside the while) and add the items from your table to the Checkbox list inside the while loop ?

Comment: my goal is when I check a checkbox some data from other table appears.So if I have USA and check it then cities from USA appear and if i check Germany cities from germany and so on..